# Who is the most powerful mutant in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, mutant

I don't see this answered definitively, there are opinions  [here and there](https://www.quora.com/Who-is-the-most-powerful-mutant-in-the-X-Men-universe) but short of having every [mutant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutant_(Marvel_Comics)) in a death match can we answer, who is the most powerful [mutant](https://www.marvel.com/characters) in the [Marvel Universe](https://www.marvel.com/explore)?

---

*One possible algorithm for determining 'more powerful'*

1. Pick an opponent, X and find an instance where X defeats a mutant
2. Eliminate *all* mutants either directly defeated by X, or by beings *defeated by X*
3. We ultimately get to a being who no mutant has defeated. Stop.
4. Pick the *last* mutant(s) that was *removed* from the list.

<sub>Note to real life coders, it will terminate since the lists are finite, and as written may fail some edge-conditions.</sub>

Comment: most powerful based on *what*? richards can create a universe, but scarlet witch can alter all of reality. richards could defeat a celesital, but wanda could make them not even exist in the first place.

Comment: I was going for combat, of course not only physical. Which mutant would win in Marvelverse combat against increasingly powerful opponents? Presumably say the [Living Tribunal](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwid8pHywb3JAhWBbhoKHbCaBlkQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLiving_Tribunal&usg=AFQjCNHW9a_1PT0xnsMInz29NOaPEuTvWg) could win over all.

Comment: The problem with your question is that we can go round and round arguing over whom can beat whom as power levels and combat abilities flux from writer to writer and story to story.

Comment: @phantom42 Got it, leave it locked. I was putting in how I came up with a solution.

Answer (score 9):

**[Franklin Benjamin Richards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Richards_(comics))**

> Franklin is a mutant beyond [Omega-Level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutant_(Marvel_Comics)#Omega-level_mutants) with vast reality-manipulating and psionic powers.<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sub>1</sub><sup>[Powers and Abilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Richards#Powers_and_abilities)</sup>

> Two Celestials, [Ashema the Listener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashema_the_Listener) and [Nezarr the Calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nezarr_the_Calculator), were at one time tasked with retrieving Franklin for evaluation as a new member of the Celestial Host.<sup>2</sup>
>
> <sub>2</sub><sup>[Heroes Reborn: The Return #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Heroes_Reborn:_The_Return_Vol_1_1)</sup>

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Richards_(comics)):

> He warps the three Celestials away to the inner sphere of a local gas giant. He then acquires an orb containing his younger counterpart's powers, which he stores within his chest. When the Celestials return, the adult Franklin again confronts them, and destroys them all in a [prolonged battle](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_604).
> In the aftermath, the adult Franklin shares a brief moment with Galactus. The two discuss the heat death of everything and the revelation of Franklin's immortality, specifically that he will, a billion years from now, stand beside Galactus to witness the birth of a new universe.

As a little boy *creates a universe in his bedroom*.

[image: The scene is a bedroom with a prominent Captain America mat, with a teddy bear and a starship Enterprise toy suggesting a young boy. The blanket on the bed is tented over an unseen figure, and a glow is radiating from it. Narrative text reads "All alone in his room..." The next frame continues "a little boy creates a baby universe." A young boy with an expression of delight is shown under the blanket as he holds a galaxy-shaped glow between his outstretched hands.]

Again as a little boy offhandedly defeats multiple [Celestials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_(comics))

[image: A blond boy and a smaller green-skinned humanoid stand on an artificial-appearing flat surface, just back of a drop of undefinite depth. The blond boy looking upwards at something says "It's weird Leech. I can hear them thinking... I think they're sick of something. So. You got any advice?" The green-skinned figure replies "Win" and the boy responds "Okay." The boy floats off the ground towards the right above the drop. Enclosed in a spherical bubble he approaches a giant orange humanoid figure at least 20 times his size. The orange giant is either wearing some kind of armor with glowing power lines or is partly mechanical; its face appears to consist only of 3 pairs of glowing eyes. The boy says "Hello. You have to stop all this." The boy floats in front of its face as the orange giant speaks "Interesting/fascinating/curious. Observing/analyzing/deconstructing... Human. Mutant... Anomaly. Beyond omega classification. Danger/threat/harbinger." From a more remote viewpoint we see the orange giant and 3 other giant figures, each with its own distinctive pattern and colouration, facing the floating boy in their midst. The orange one continues "Destroy/terminate/end." With a loud "ZAAAKKK" beams shoot from each of its six eyes.]

[image: The beams converge on the boy, stopped somehow before they reach him. The boy says "That's weird. Why would you shoot flowers at me?" and a cloud of flowers flies away from him. The beams gone, the boy faces the celestials as flowers continue to fly around him. He says "And why are they growing out of your head?" A blue celestial, with a humanoid face and greenish-white glowing lines exclaims "!" as yellow-flowering vines start to grow all over it.]

Comment: Does that mean the celestials are an association, rather than a race?

Comment: Well at least we know they can [merge](http://www.comicvine.com/forums/battles-7/the-galactus-engine-cancerverse-adult-franklin-ric-1724286/) to create an even more poweful entity.